# Lifetime of format!() in match expression is too short

Tags: rust

I am implementing a custom `Display::fmt` for my own struct which represent an interval.

```
struct Range<T> {
    lower: Option<T>,
    upper: Option<T>,
}
```

A range could be `Range { lower: Some(1), upper: None }`, which means it contains all integers from 1 up to infinity (or the limit of `i32` I suppose).

I want to implement `Display::fmt` to use `T`'s `Display::fmt` if the bound is not `None` and to display an empty string otherwise:

```
let range = Range { lower: Some(1), upper: None }
println!("{}", range); // Prints <1,>

let range = Range { lower: Some(1), upper: Some(10) }
println!("{}", range); // Prints <1,10>

let range = Range { lower: None, upper: Some(10) }
println!("{}", range); // Prints <,10>
```

I have started my implementation but have trouble with the `match` expression and the lifetime of the string produced by `format!()`. The problem with my implementation is that the string returned by format doesn't live long enough to be used further down.

```
fn main() {
    let opt = Some(1);

    let opt_display = match opt {
        Some(x) => &format!("{}", x), // error: borrowed value does not live long enough
        None => "",
    };

    println!("opt: {}", opt_display);
}
```

Why doesn't my approach work and what is a good solution to my problem?

Comment: Thank you for the great answers. I chose to accept Shepmaster's answer since it described why my solution didn't work the best, as well as presenting multiple solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Emilgardis has already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253533/155423), you are trying to return a reference to a value that will be dropped while the reference is still around. Congratulations, you just tried to create memory unsafety that would have caused a crash (or worse) in C or C++, but Rust prevented it!

One efficiency improvement you can make is to only allocate in one case:

```
fn main() {
    let opt = Some(1);
    let opt_display = opt.map(|s| format!("{}", s));

    // Type not needed, only used to assert the type is what we expect
    let opt_display_str: &str = opt_display.as_ref().map(String::as_str).unwrap_or("");
    println!("opt: {}", opt_display_str);
}
```

You could also use a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), which allows either an owned or borrowed string. Note how similar it is to the other answer, but this doesn't allocate in the case of `None`:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let opt = Some(1);

    let opt_display: Cow<str> = match opt {
        Some(ref x) => format!("{}", x).into(),
        None => "".into(),
    };

    println!("opt: {}", opt_display);
}
```

> I want to implement `Display::fmt`

The *best* thing to do is probably to avoid any allocation then. You will be handed a formatter that you `write!` to, just call `write!` in each match arm. This might introduce a bit of duplication, but is probably more efficient. Without the formatter, it would look something like:

```
fn main() {
    let opt = Some(1);

    print!("opt: ");

    if let Some(ref x) = opt  {
       print!("{}", x);
    }

    println!("");    
}
```

Substitute `write!(f,` for `print!(` inside the formatter and return on error.

Comment: The `if let Some(ref x) =` solution is exactly what I am looking for. I now understand why my previous code didn't work. Working in Rust is certainly eye-opening. Thank you for the thourough run-down.

Comment: When doing multiple `write!(` in sequence each seems to return a Result of some kind. The compiler displays `warning: unused result which must be used, ...`. I currently ignore that warning using `#[allow(unused_must_use)]`. Is there any way `write!` on a `fmt::Formatter` can fail? Is this bad practice?

Comment: @antennen yes, and? Use the `Result`, just like everywhere else in Rust, likely by "returning on error", like I mention. Perhaps a refresher with the [error handling chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html) of *The Rust Programming Language* would help? See also [Chris Emerson's answer who so kindly wrote out the entire implementation for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41260867/155423).

Comment: @antennen *Is there any way `write!` on a `fmt::Formatter` can fail?* — absolutely. The disk could be full, the file could have been closed, the network became unplugged... etc. *Is this bad practice?* Ignoring errors? Absolutely a bad idea, which is why the compiler tells you that you should use the `Result`.

Comment: I have yet to read the error handling chapter. I started learning Rust yesterday by reading "the book". Very interesting language. I will look into it!

Answer (score 6):

I'm no expert on lifetimes, but I believe the problem here is that you are trying to return a `&String` from a `String` created by `format!` inside the match. Since the scope of the format is only inside the scope, the borrow checker complains.

To fix this you can use an owned string.

```
fn main() {
    let opt = Some(1);

    let opt_display = match opt {
        Some(ref x) => format!("{}", x), // Allowed since opt_display now owns the string
        None => "".into(),
    };
    // Another way to achieve the same thing.
    //let opt_display = opt.map(|s| format!("{}", s)).unwrap_or("".into());

    println!("opt: {}", opt_display);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When implementing `Display`, there's no need to return strings; you can just `write!()` into the provided formatter.

It would look like:

```
impl<T: Display> Display for Range<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        write!(fmt, "<")?;
        if let Some(v) = self.lower {
            write!(fmt, "{}", v)?;
        }
        write!(fmt, ",")?;
        if let Some(v) = self.upper {
            write!(fmt, "{}", v)?;
        }
        write!(fmt, ">")
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6d7a0ae8310d4f495ec5bb4807e8430c&version=stable&backtrace=0)